# Can't open RFKILL control device: No such file or directory

Tags: wireless, rfkill

I have accendentily deleted /dev/rfkill file. Now when I run `rfkill list`. It gives me this error. How to restore the rfkill. ?

Comment: have you tried running `sudo apt-get install rfkill`?

Comment: Device files would normally get created dynamically during the boot process I think. I would expect it to come back when you reboot.

Comment: @steeldriver  I have created a empty file myself. Then it started giving me this Error "WrONG SIZE of rfkill event". And yes rebooted helped fixed the issue. Please add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method with `wget` - meaning the target must have an Internet connection.

```bsh
cd /lib/firmware
mkdir rtlwifi
cd rtlwifi
wget http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

The device is created by **rkill module** - if you really have is as a module, the device will be possibly recreated when you remove the module by **rmmod** and load it again with **modprobe**. Man pages are your friends.

The device /dev/rfkill is special **character device with major number 10 and minor number 242**, so I guess it shoud be possible to create it with **mknod** command. The proper permissions are probably 'read by all, write by group and owner' and the owner is likely to be root.

The reboot is the last resort :).